# How to use native library with structure / union

Tags: java, structure, union, jna

In my project, I use a native method declared in an interface with JNA:

```java
short sSmartInstCardEx(InstallCard pxInstallCard);
```

My object class InstallCard is declared as:

```java
public class InstallCard extends Structure {
    public int xCardType;

    protected List<String> getFieldOrder() {
        return Arrays.asList("xCardType", "ucProtocolType", "ucAddReader");}
}

public class Install_CD97_GTML extends InstallCard {
    public byte ucProtocolType;
    public byte ucAddReader;
}
```

In my Main, I call it like this:

```java
Install_CD97_GTML pxInstallCardCD97 = new Install_CD97_GTML();
pxInstallCardCD97.xCardType = 1;
pxInstallCardCD97.ucAddReader = 0;
pxInstallCardCD97.ucProtocolType = 1;

res = ReaderThalesApi.INSTANCE.sSmartInstCardEx(pxInstallCardCD97);
```

This case is working well, my native library replies correctly.

I would like to construct my pxInstallCardCD97 parameter differently, so I keep my InstallCard class, but I change the other:

```java
public class InstallCard extends Structure {

    public int xCardType;

    protected List<String> getFieldOrder() {
        return Arrays.asList("xCardType", "ucProtocolType", "ucAddReader");
    }
}

public class Install_CD97_GTML extends InstallCard {
    public CD97_GTML_Parameter iCardParam;
}
```

And I introduce a CD97-GTML_Parameter class:

```java
public class CD97_GTML_Parameter {
    public byte ucProtocolType;
    public byte ucAddReader;
}
```

I call it in my Main like this:

```java
Install_CD97_GTML pxInstallCardCD97 = new Install_CD97_GTML();
CD97_GTML_Parameter pxCD97_GTML_Parameter = new CD97_GTML_Parameter();
pxInstallCardCD97.xCardType = 1;
pxCD97_GTML_Parameter.ucAddReader = 0;
pxCD97_GTML_Parameter.ucProtocolType = 1;
pxInstallCardCD97.iCardParam = pxCD97_GTML_Parameter;

res = ReaderThalesApi.INSTANCE.sSmartInstCardEx(pxInstallCardCD97);
```

In this case, I get an error:

> Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Invalid Structure field in class Install_CD97_GTML, field name 'iCardParam' (class CD97_GTML_Parameter): The type "CD97_GTML_Parameter" is not supported: Native size for type "CD97_GTML_Parameter" is unknown    at com.sun.jna.Structure.validateField(Structure.java:1246)     at com.sun.jna.Structure.validateFields(Structure.java:1255)    at com.sun.jna.Structure.(Structure.java:211)     at com.sun.jna.Structure.(Structure.java:204)     at com.sun.jna.Structure.(Structure.java:191)     at com.sun.jna.Structure.(Structure.java:183)     at InstallCard.(InstallCard.java:6)   at Install_CD97_GTML.(Install_CD97_GTML.java:4)   at Principal.main(Principal.java:70) Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: The type "CD97_GTML_Parameter" is not supported: Native size for type "CD97_GTML_Parameter" is unknown  at com.sun.jna.Native.getNativeSize(Native.java:1412)   at com.sun.jna.Structure.getNativeSize(Structure.java:2310)     at com.sun.jna.Structure.getNativeSize(Structure.java:2300)     at com.sun.jna.Structure.validateField(Structure.java:1242)     ... 8 more

I don't really understand what is meant, and what is the difference between both solutions.

To be clear, my goal is to map my class/object with the native structure given in the Native library documentation:

```c
short sSmartInstCardEx(const InstallCard \*pxInstallCard);

typedef struct
{
  UCHAR   ucProtocolType;
  UCHAR   ucAddReader;
  Install_CD97_GTML;

typedef union
{
  Install_CD97_GTML   xCd97Param;
  Install_CD98_GTML     xCd98Param;
  Install_CD99_GTML      xCd99Param;
  ....
  InstallCardParam;

typedef struct
{
  eTypCardType        xCardType;
  InstallCardParam    iCardParam;
  InstallCard;
```

Comment: Please repost the exception stacktrace formatted in a code block, so it isn't a jumble.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is your class `public class CD97_GTML_Parameter` does not extend `Structure` so JNA doesn't know how to use it.

Instead of changing the `Install_CD97_GTML` class like this you can perform a transformation step to a class structure you prefer.

```
public class Friendly_Install_CD97_GTML {
    public final int xCardType;
    public final CD97_GTML_Parameter iCardParam;

    public Friendly_Install_CD97_GTML(int xCardType, byte ucProtocolType, byte ucAddReader) {
        this.xCardType = xCardType;
        this.iCardParam = new CD97_GTML_Parameter(ucProtocolType, ucAddReader);
    }
}

public class CD97_GTML_Parameter {

    public final byte ucProtocolType; public final byte ucAddReader;

    public CD97_GTML_Parameter(byte ucProtocolType, byte ucAddReader) {
        this.ucProtocolType = ucProtocolType;
        this.ucAddReader = ucAddReader;
    }
}


public Friendly_Install_CD97_GTML friendlyConvert(Install_CD97_GTML raw) {
    return new Friendly_Install_CD97_GTML(raw.xCardType, raw.ucProtocolType, raw.ucAddReader);
}
```